# Zero - based index

Tags: c, timer

Does anyone know what this means

> param[in]    timer        /*The zero-based index of the timer.  *
>
> param[in]   delay_us    /*The time to delay for, in microseconds.  */
>
> void Timer_Wait(const uint8_t timer, const uint32_t delay_us);

and this is the address mapping

> Timer 0 0x80000000 Timer 1 0x80000100

I would just like to know what it means by "Zero - Based index of the timer"

Thank you

Comment: It means that `0` is the index for the first timer, `1` is the index for the next timer, and so on.  That is also indicated in the address mapping you show ("Timer 0", "Timer 1").

Comment: You should accept an answer to your questions.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong here but then if i wanted to use timer 1 in the function timer wait, is the following okay `uint8_t timer1 = 100 ` and then in the main program `timer_wait(timer1,1000);`

Comment: @user1175889: it seems to me that if you wanted to use timer 1 (the timer at address `0x80000100` you should call `timer_wait( 1, 1000)`.  But that's just going by the comment (which are sometimes notoriously misleading, imprecise, or plain wrong). To know for certain, there should be some docs that are more precise/clear or you could look at the source for `timer_wait()` if it's available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero based means if you have three timers, they are numbered 0,1,2 as opposed to 1,2,3.

Answer (score 1):

Zero based indexing means that the first element of an array is index 0.
So far example:

int numbers[] = {1,2,3,4};

If you want the first element in the array you would use numbers[0]  ( which is 1 ). 
However, the index of the element in the array that contains 1 is 0  ( numbers[0] ).

So basically if you want the nth element in an array you would use nth-1 is the index. 
Example: 
You want to print 3. It's the 3rd element but index 2. 
printf("%d\n", numbers[ 3-1 ]);

Answer (score 0):

It means the first parameter is the timer index, and the index of the first timer is 0.